# Dependant random variables with covariance equal to $0$

Tags: statistics

I need to find a pair of dependent random variables $(X, Y)$ with covariance equal to $0.$ From this I gather:

$$0 = E((X-EX)(Y-EY)) = E \left(\left(X - \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)\,dx\right) \left(Y - \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_Y(x)\,dx \right)\right)$$

but what can I do now? How can I use the fact that they are dependent in the equation? Do you know of two such variables?

Comment: If you make $Y$ dependent on $X$ and give $X$ an expectation of $0$, say $X = -1$ with $p = 0.5$ and $X = 1$ with $p = 0.5$ then the covariance would surely be 0, no? I could be very wrong. $X$ and $Y$ are dependent iff $P(X = x$ and $Y = y) \neq P(X = x) .P(Y = y)$.

Comment: Take a look at (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/121598)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable that takes on the values $1$ or $-1$ with equal probability.  Let $Y$ be a random variable where $Y=0$ if $X=-1$, and $Y$ is  $-1$ or $1$ with equal probability if $X=1$.

Then $X$ and $Y$ depend on each other, since if you know what $Y$ is then you know what $X$ is. However, their covariance is zero:

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)
&= E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)\\\\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$

since

$$\begin{align*}
E(XY)
&= (-1\cdot 0 \cdot P(X=-1, Y=0)) +(1\cdot -1 \cdot P(X=1, Y=-1))+(1\cdot 1 \cdot P(X=1, Y=1)) \\\\
&= 0-P(X=1, Y=-1)+P(X=1,Y=1)\\\\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$

and

$E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ are both zero.

This illustrates how random variables can be dependent but have no correlation, and thus no covariance.

[image]

Correlation is a measure of linear dependence. It is possible for two random variables to be uncorrelated but nonlinearly dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try $X$ and $X^2$ where the distribution of $X$ is symmetric about $0$.

Comment: Thank you, but I am a bit confused by $X^2$. Say X is a continuous random variable that can be anything between $-1$ and $1$ with equal probability. In other words $P(a < X < b) = \frac{b-a}{2}$. What is $X^2$ here?

Comment: Whatever $X$ is, $X^2$ is its square.  It can be anything from $0$ to $1$, and if $0 \le a < b \le 1$, $P(a < X^2 < b) = P(\sqrt{a} < X < \sqrt{b}) + P(-\sqrt{b} < X < -\sqrt{a}) = \sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: The simplest example may be this: $Y= X^2$ and $X = \begin{cases} \phantom{-}1, \\ \phantom{-}0, & \text{each with probability } 1/3. \\ -1. \end{cases} \qquad$

Comment: This answer is considerably more than anything that should be called a "hint".

Comment: I was looking for a continuous random variable example to make sure I understand it before moving on.